Driving truck on rocky trail
I plan to build a cabin at the end of a 500 metre rocky trail in Eastern Ontario. I want to drive my 2010 Silverado 1500 4wd (new winter tires) on the trail to bring building supplies to the cabin site.

The trail is bedrock that's covered in moss, with some rocky dips and bumps. The rock is a gritty/grippy schist, not overly slippery. I'll drive when the moss is fully dry; it seems too slippery when wet.
An ATV has driven the trail without issue, even when wet. I have not driven a vehicle on the trail yet.
There isn't a safety risk to the driver of the truck; there are no steep areas. There will be another person with a truck to assist if needed.
I plan to fill in rocky dips as best I can by hand shovelling and wheelbarrowing sand from down the road, but the trail will always have rocky bumps in places.


I figure there is a risk of damaging my truck on the rocky bumps. When offroading on rocky terrain, what kind of vehicle damage is most common?
The site is 3 km from the nearest public road, so towing or repairs would be quite a headache.
I want to know what to watch out for in terms of damage to the vehicle and avoid issues if I can.

Edit: Photos of the underside of the truck:



I don't see anything that looks especially vulnerable like the oil pan or oil filter being exposed. The only thing I noticed was a corner of the front differential(?) that pokes out a bit. There's nothing behind the plastic diagonal cover, just empty space.

Any skid plates? Where is your oil filter, if not covered by a skid plate? Most other damage won't prevent you getting the vehicle back out, but losing your engine oil will.

@JonCuster No, I don't have any skid plates yet. The skid plates I've found online for the oil filter seem to be designed to bolt to an aftermarket bumper, which I don't have. So I'm not sure what to do in terms of a skid plate.

How deep are the actual dips? Have you driven the trail without a load in the truck? At slow speed, the big things would seem to be approach/takeoff/breakover angles.

@JonCuster The dips are gradual but enough to bottom out the truck or hit the front bumper. Any pictures I've taken don't do the dips justice; it just looks like a pleasant, mossy, grassy road. But there's hidden rock everywhere to bang the truck on. If the moss wasn't there it'd look much more severe. I'll try again to get a photo of the cross-section next time I'm on-site, but it's 3 hours away. In the meantime, he're a poor excuse of a diagram: https://i.sstatic.net/53t6X9bH.png. I haven't driven the trail at all yet in a truck. I only saw a neighbor drive it once with a ATV.

Not being familiar with the Silverado, I'd guess that your suspension is just regular on-road suspension, so it will struggle to handle off-road and probably doesn't have enough clearance - only 9" (23 cm) according to some websites. With a load on clearance will decrease and alter the front handling. I think you'll struggle with that vehicle and a load.

On a 500m road, if you do want to persist and have another person, I'd ask them to walk outside and keep you appraised of what the bigger potholes are looking like when you get to them.  Make sure there is no risk to them, of course.  That diagram looks a bit sketchy to take on though.  I don't think I'd even bother trying to shovel in sand, but strategically placed rocks/gravel might be helpful on particularly deep spots.  Or try laying a corduroy road in those spots.

Sand is likely to be squashed out by the vehicle, and washed out by rain. Hoggin would be more stable.

Frankly I'm thinking you should rent a Bobcat (or similar) for a weekend and go have some fun. Either fill in the low spots (way more easily than a shovel and wheelbarrow), or you may well find out that the weak planes of the schist are just right for smoothing the road (and filling with the schist off the tops).

What are you planning to do once the cabin is built?  Walk the 500m or drive them?  That changes your calculations on how permanent adjustments need to be.

@ItalianPhilosopher Good point. I would want to drive to the cabin long after it is built, too. So that means I should improve the trail so that it is easily drivable as soon as feasible. With that said, everything takes ten times as long in the bush, especially on a shoestring budget, and when only working on weekends.

Without seeing the actual ground truth, lets talk about what might result in a major, non-recoverable situation.
If the major topography features are perpendicular to the trail, your major geometry considerations are the approach angle (will your front bumper hit before the wheels start lifting the front end), the takeoff angle (will the tailgate bottom out), and the breakover angle (will the vehicle get high-centered). The first two result in scraping of steel on rock. A load in the back exacerbates the tailgate dragging. High centering is the much more painful one and may well require a winch, but your frame is more than capable of holding up the truck (your sidesteps may not like it though). Note that a winch could be a nice thing to have on your construction site anyway. These outcomes generally are recoverable and yield minimal structural damage. Once free you can drive away.
Where you can get into major trouble is where rocks stick up in the middle of the trail in places where your truck, while maneuvering, will come down onto something critical. The big big problem is your oil filter which, if snapped off, drains your engine oil and before you notice it may well cause major engine damage. Check where your oil filter is - it may well be up and out of harms way. Next problem is you gas tank, but those usually are steel and will more likely dent than hole (depends on just what rock you hit). Having some J-B Weld putty or similar and 5 gallons of gas will get you out.
I've scraped the frame on my Tacoma. Now, it has a shorter wheelbase, so I'm less concerned about getting high-centered. Earlier, taking a Honda CR-V places it really should not have gone, I managed to have a rock take out my evap cannister, which was tucked up "out of the way" near the gas tank. While that required getting it repaired later, it did not prevent completion of the trip.
Pretty much anything else that happens from scraping or dragging, while not fun, will not prevent you from getting out.
Now, what would I do? You are going to want to move dirt for your construction site. I'd rent a Bobcat for a weekend (or week), trailer it up there, and spend the first day or two working on the road. Depending on the bedding planes of the schist, the Bobcat might well take the tops of the bumps right off, and then use that as fill for the low spots (watch how sharp the rubble is though). Then fill as needed using sand/soil/whatnot that is available. The Bobcat will make it much easier than doing it by hand. Spend the rest of the time preparing a parking area, laydown yard, and the foundation of the cabin.
Before working on the road, it would be good to have your second person closely watch how the (unloaded) truck manages the topography. Depending on how much you trust them, it might be even better for you to be the one outside watching the clearances everywhere as your buddy slowly moves along. You might well be surprised at just how well things go.

Something to consider as well would be to take side photos of particularly problematic sections as the truck goes over:  a smartphone will tag them with the exact GPS coordinates and you can use those to plan where to prioritize adjustments.

Thanks! I added some photos of the truck undercarriage to the question. It looks like everything is well protected, except maybe the corner of the front differential(?), which pokes out a bit.
